# Saving plot values to a .dat file

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, while-loop

1. I need to know how to save data generated from a `np.random.uniform`
   command to a `.dat` file.
2. I have already successfully saved the first set of data using
   `np.savetext`, but I am having trouble getting the next values to append after.
3. I feel like a simple `i=i=1` would do the trick but I'm getting
   nowhere.

Comment: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: did you try to put all sets in list and save this list ?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:

```
import numpy as np

with open('output.dat', 'ba') as datfile:
    for _ in range(3):
        value = np.random.uniform(size=(2,2))
        np.savetxt(datfile, value)
```

This is how the output file looks like:

```
6.302102149257778896e-01 9.997718979690175534e-01
9.057963595031988113e-01 8.977332622537474993e-01
4.832210145214395070e-01 7.278483457892492847e-01
6.789409262108637710e-01 1.110638380803604663e-01
9.912427716841673009e-01 5.394967355459017178e-01
```

Comment: The values that need to be saved are within a while loop and are floats for x, y, and z values. Because of this, I cannot use range or length in the for loop.

Comment: Oh, I see. I used range here just to demonstrate how you could append to an output file. For float values you can get a file object using open() as in the example above and then just pass the formatted argument to its write() method. If you share some code I can help you modify it to get the exact output you need.